# Node and MongoDB update transaction and return response when done

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using Node and Mongodb to update transactions from a react app.  After updating I want to receive a response of either success or error.

In my setup the app API calls the code below.  The code works find and the updates are successful.  How can I return a response to my api after the updates are done to display a success or an error if there is one?  I can't do it in UpdateDB cause the response is not accessible.  Should I be setting this up differently?

```
exports.updateTransactions = function(req, res) {
    console.log('update transtest function entered with req.body value: ', req.body);

    let transactions = req.body.transUpdate;
    let returnType = req.body.returnType;
    let year = req.body.year;

    let transid;
    let category;
    let notes;

    for (var i = 0, len = transactions.length; i < len; i++) {
        transid = parseInt(transactions[i].transid);
        category = transactions[i].category;
        notes = transactions[i].notes;

        var update = {
            $set: {
                category: category,
                notes: notes
            }
        };

        var filter = {
            transid: transid
        };

        UpdateDB(filter,update)
    }
}

function UpdateDB (filter, update){
  db.collection('transtest', function(err, collection) {
      collection.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update,function(err, items) {
      });
  });
}
```

Comment: I gave the answer let me know if it worked or not. :)

Comment: Thanks. I tried but it didn't work.

Comment: Are you getting any error? And is it saving the document to the db?

Comment: Here is the error: `SyntaxError: C:/dev/prog/expenses/db/dataService.js: await is a reserved word (213:12)
  211 |
  212 |         try {
> 213 |             await UpdateDB(filter,update);
      |             ^
  214 |         } catch (error) {
  215 |             return error;
  216 |         }`

Comment: Did you add that async keyword before function?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be solved using `async` `await` and `try` `catch` feature of javascript.
Here I have written some code that might be helpful.
Make these chnages to your code and try if it worked or not.

```
exports.updateTransactions = async function (req, res) {
    // ...
    for (var i = 0, len = transactions.length; i < len; i++) {
        // ... 
        try {
            await UpdateDB(filter, update);
        } catch (error) {
            return error;
        }
    }
    return "success";
}

async function UpdateDB(filter, update) {
    var collection = await db.collection('transtest');
    await collection.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update);
}
```